# How to check for 3 consequtive letters in a string?

Tags: c#, string, loops

My program needs to check for 3 consecutive letters in a string (and check through the whole string). I could make it check for them in a harcoded manner, like "check for qwe", "check for "wer", check for "ert", but that looks messy and badly done.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    string BadLetters = "qwertyuiopasdfghjklzxcvbnm";
    string password = "Blablauio"; 

    for (int i = 1; i <= 30; i++)
    {
        // This checks if it contains "qwe" but i want it to 
        // cycle through the rest (such as "wer" or "rty")
        if (password.Contains(BadLetters.Substring(0, 3)))             {
            Console.WriteLine("password contains 3 consequtive letters in BadLetters");                    
        }
    }

    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

The problem is that this only checks the first 3 letters of BadLetters (qwe), and it doesn't look for "ert", etc.

Comment: What's `firstletter` and `secondletter`?

Comment: Sorry they should have been declared as 0 and 3, imagine they say 0 and 3, i want it to cycle to 1 and 4, 2 and 5, etc. so it checks through parts of the string

Comment: Proposal: Loop while `i < BadLetters.Length - 3` and check with `password.Contains(BadLetters.Substring(i, 3))`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would be better if you loop on the password variable instead, like this:

```
    string badLetters = "qwertyuiopasdfghjklzxcvbnm";
    string password = "Blablauio"; 
    for (int i = 0; i < password.Length-2; i++)
    {
        if (badLetters.Contains(password.Substring(i,3))) 
        {
            Console.WriteLine("password contains 3 consequtive letters in BadLetters");
        }
    }
```

Obviously you also have to check that the password is at least 3 characters.
This loop could fail on keyboard row crossing letters, i.e. "opa" or "pas", that should be considered right values, so you could do this instead:

```
string badLettersR1 = "qwertyuiop";
string badLettersR2 = "asdfghjkl";
string badLettersR3 = "zxcvbnm";
string password = "Blablauio"; 
for (int i = 0; i < password.Length-2; i++)
{
    if (badLettersR1.Contains(password.Substring(i,3)) ||
        badLettersR2.Contains(password.Substring(i,3)) ||
        badLettersR3.Contains(password.Substring(i,3))) 
    {
        Console.WriteLine("password contains 3 consequtive letters in BadLetters");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try to edit your string, so the 3 letters are gone and then you do the same job as before for the next ones.

Or you can add to the 2 variables `firstletter` and `secondletter` 4 so it skips the first 3 as well and is repeating with the following ones

Sry i understood your string as 3 in a row...

Answer (score 0):

You need to iterate through each character in `password`, find its index in `BadLetters`, and check if the next two characters in `password` match the next two in `BadLetters`. I also changed the stop condition of the `for loop` because you only need to iterate through the antepenultimate character in `password`

```
string BadLetters = "qwertyuiopasdfghjklzxcvbnm";
string password = "Blablauio";
for (int i = 0; i < password.Length - 2; i++)
{
    var j = BadLetters.IndexOf(password[i]);
    if (j > -1 && j + 2 < BadLetters.Length &&
        password[i + 1] == BadLetters[j + 1] &&
        password[i + 2] == BadLetters[j + 2])
    {
        Console.WriteLine("password contains 3 consequtive letters in BadLetters");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

## TL; DR

You could just go through array of symbols and compare it's indexes like this:

```
if (BadLetters.IndexOf(my_word[i]) - BadLetter.IndexOf(my_word[i-1]) == 1) {
     Console.WriteLine("Consequent letters detected!");
}
```

you could just **count consequent letters** and alert when count more then **3**

I provide detailed code with all lines from keyboard. And you could add another lines (i.e. upper case) without any modification of code.

You also have control on `N` - number of forbidden consequent characters in string.

Also there is `Check` method which using only for demonstrate results of working:

```
q - ok
qw - ok
qwe - password contains 3 consequtive letters in BadLetters
abdfsk - ok
ehjk - password contains 3 consequtive letters in BadLetters
bnm - password contains 3 consequtive letters in BadLetters
```

## The code

Code on .net fiddle: https://dotnetfiddle.net/4oILkj

```C#
public static String[] KeyboardLines = new [] {
    "1234567890", 
    "qwertyuiop[]", 
    "asdfghjkl;'\\", 
    "`zxcvbnm,./"
};

public static Int32 GetLine(char c){
    for (int i = 0; i < KeyboardLines.Length; i++) {
        if (KeyboardLines[i].IndexOf(c) > -1) {
            return i;
        };
    }
    return -1;
}

public static bool HasConsequenceLetters(string str, int n = 3) {
    if (str.Length < n) { 
        return false;
    }

    char previousLetter = str[0];
    int previousLine = GetLine(previousLetter);
    int previousLetterIndex = KeyboardLines[previousLine].IndexOf(previousLetter);
    Int32 consequentLettersCount = 1;


    for (int i = 1; i < str.Length; i++) {
        var currentLetter = str[i];
        var currentLine = GetLine(currentLetter);
        var currentLetterIndex = KeyboardLines[currentLine].IndexOf(currentLetter);

        if (currentLine != -1 && currentLine == previousLine) {
            if (currentLetterIndex - previousLetterIndex == 1) {
                consequentLettersCount += 1;
            }
        }
        else {
            consequentLettersCount = 1;
        }

        if (consequentLettersCount == n) {
            return true;
        }

        previousLetter = currentLetter;
        previousLetterIndex = currentLetterIndex;
        previousLine = currentLine;
    }
    return false;
}
```

## Improvements

This approach could be improved if `GetLine` function will return character index with line number and then compare not just characters but pairs (LetterLine, LetterIndex). But this require from us to using tuples or classes but I don't think you really want this.

Answer (score 0):

The simple one I found is

```
using System;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        string BadLetters = "qwertyuiopasdfghjklzxcvbnm";
        string password = "Blablauio";
        Console.WriteLine(password.IndexOf(BadLetters.Substring(0,3))>=0?"Present":"Not Present");
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

You may need to check for null condition of both strings